# wamp server: set up virtual host

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver

I am setting a virtual host with wamp server following this tutorial
http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       dev.gamenomad.com
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\dev.gamenomad.com\public"
    ServerName dev.gamenomad.com
    ServerAlias dev.gamenomad.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dev.gamenomad.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dev.gamenomad.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<Directory C:\wamp\www>
    Order Deny,Allow   
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I am unable to access dev.gamenomad.com . I got this error

```
i18n-values: Missing value for "primaryParagraph"
GET http://dev.gamenomad.com/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED      http://dev.gamenomad.com/:1
```

fyi, my apache server listen to port 8080 instead of the default 80. Does it affect my virtual host?

Comment: `fyi, my apache server listen to port 8080 instead of the default 80. Does it affect my virtual host?` **YES OF COURSE IT DOES**

Comment: That tutorial is missing a few things, [try reading this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) It was approached from a different prespective but it does tell you how to create Virtual Hosts

Answer (score 0):

For wamp, you can set a virtual host using swamp UI as well. For that, you need to left-click on wamp icon -> Your Virtual hosts -> VirtualHost Management.

[image]

Then, just enter the server name, absolute path to the folder and then create the virtual host.

[image]

You can check it yourself [here](https://www.noobietech.com/create-a-virtual-host-in-wamp-windows/#method-B)

Answer (score -1):

Use gamenomad.git instead dev.gamenomad.com
And directory like Document root and goto c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc
Open the "hosts" file
And goto end line and type
127.0.0.1         gamenomad.git

Save change as administrator
 End